# Weird issues with semicolons, and with 'cannot resolve ...'

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have been following up on a tutorial on Android App Development recently, but my code doesn't build due to some errors. I've done what the errors told me (place semicolons), but that caused a unexpected token error to occur.

This is my code:

```
package nl.yourikuilman.android.ultimatemcnews;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static nl.yourikuilman.android.ultimatemcnews.fun.showNewsFragment;

public class MainActivity {
    public void AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun;
            onCreate(savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                showNewsFragment();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class fun {
    public static void showNewsFragment(){
        val tag="NewsListFragment";
        val existingFragmentWithTag=supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

        if(existingFragmentWithTag==null){
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.newsListFragmentContainer,NewsListFragment(),tag)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have written it in Android Studio, and also work with Kotlin in the same project. This is the error list for my java code (in order that Android Studio threw at me):

> - Cannot resolve symbol 'override'
> - Cannot resolve method 'onCreate(?)'
> - Cannot resolve symbol 'savedInstanceState'
> - Cannot resolve method 'onCreate(?)'
> - Cannot resolve symbol 'savedInstanceState'
> - Cannot resolve method 'setContentView(int)'
> - Cannot resolve symbol 'val' (got this 2 times in a row)
> - Cannot resolve symbol 'supportFragmentManager' (got this 2 times in a row)
> - Method call expected (this is a note from Android Studio, not an error) [this points
>     '.add(R.id.newsListFragmentContainer,NewsListFragment(),tag)' out,
>     more specific: 'NewsListFragment()' is pointed out].

Comment: Never used Kotlin before. But is this code supposed to be java or Kotlin? If it is Java then there are lots of things that are wrong here. I'll explain after getting your answer

Comment: you cannot nest one activity into the other... and you should initialize your variables, before using them.

Comment: don't need semicolon after fun `override fun; onCreate`

Comment: It seems like you mix java and kotlin in single file. You should keep java code and kotlin code separately.

Comment: There is no `static` and `void` keywords in kotlin. Read about [`companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) and [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions) instead.

Comment: @GeorgeArokiam it is supposed to be java. I use kotlin to handle firebase in different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using semicolons in Kotlin code like you would in Java -- they are unnecessary clutter. Your code should be more along the lines of:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showNewsFragment()
    }

    fun showNewsFragment() {
        val tag = "NewsListFragment"
        val existingFragmentWithTag = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)

        if (existingFragmentWithTag == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.newsListFragmentContainer, NewsListFragment(), tag)
                    .commit()
        }
    }

}
```

Just as an aside: if you are not already familiar with Java, I would stick with it until you understand the basics before picking up Kotlin. It will help you in the long run especially when working with Android (since most libraries and the SDK are Java). Also: while Java/Kotlin have 100% interop, they still need to be in separate files (your example was mixing both languages).